# Not storing POST data (json)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have this bit of javascript:

```
var jsonString = "some string of json";
$.post('proxy.php', { data : jsonString }, function(response) {
    var print = response;
    alert(print);
```

and this bit of PHP (in proxy.php):

```
       $json = $_POST['json'];

       //set POST variables, THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO POST TO!
       $url = 'http://my.site.com/post';

       //open connection
       $ch = curl_init();

       //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=" . urlencode($json));

       //execute post (the result will be something like {"result":1,"error":"","pic":"43248234af832048","code":"234920348239048"})
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       $response = json_decode($result);

       $imageHref = 'http://my.site.com/render?picid=' . $response['picid'];

       //close connection   
       curl_close($ch);

       echo $imageHref;
```

I am trying to post data to an external site using a proxy.  From there, I append the picid that the site responds with and append it to the URL to get the image URL.

Am I missing something here?  I am not getting anything in response and it seems like my data is not even being posted (when I try echo $json after the first line in proxy.php, I get an empty string).  Why am I not able to echo the JSON?  Is my implementation correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Javascript code, you are using this :

```
{ data : jsonString }
```

So, from your PHP code, should you not be reading from `$_POST['data']`, instead of `$_POST['json']` ?

If necessary, you can use [**`var_dump()`**](http://www.php.net/var_dump) to see what's in `$_POST` :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

**Edit after the comment :** if you are getting a JSON result such as this :

```
{"result":1,"error":"","pic":"43248234af832048","code":"234920348239048"}
```

This is a JSON object -- which means, after decoding it, you should access it as an object in PHP :

```
$response = json_decode($result);
echo $response->pic;
```

Note : I don't see a `picid` element in that object -- maybe you should instead use pic ?

Here too, though, you might want to use `var_dump()`, to see how your data looks like :

```
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I was something like 32 seconds faster than you ? ;-) Hell ^^

Comment: Yes! I correctly get data now. Another quick question though: Am I appending the JSON data picid correctly to the end of the URL?

Comment: it was supposed to be picid in the json object.  So the line where I save it to $imageHref, am I correctly getting the picid and appending it to the end of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
```

or even better do

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see what is actually in your post when you start